# Can I declare a view composer for a Form or HTML macro in Laravel 4?

Tags: view, macros, laravel-4

I have a partial view that I am using to provide a pair of form select fields, and both sets of options depend on some variables set by a view composer for this view.

I would like to implement this view as a `Form::macro` instead so that I can parameterize some parts of it.  However, I'm not sure how I can point the view composer at a macro instead of a partial view.  Is this even possible?

I could go the route of pointing the composer at any view that I'm using the macro in, but I'd much rather have the option data load automatically any time I use the macro as it is a common component in my web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use partials for some Bootstrap UI components, and create a macro to connect data into the template, so I only use `HTML::macro` or `Form::macro` to access them:

`Form::macro('myMacro', function($data) {
   return View::make('myPartial', $data);
};`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the primary question, but one way I can get what I want is to use View::Make instead of @include in my views.

Where I was using:

```
@include('thepartial')
```

I can use something like this instead:

```
{{ View::make('thepartial')->with(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2, ...) }}
```

This way I get the parameterization I want, and I still get the composer's effects.

Comment: You can do `@include('thepartial', array('param1' => $param1, ...))`